# how to make a grid to add rows in a certain visual state? (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to have a Grid that automatically adds rows or columns if a visual state was triggered. 
I have tried everything that I know and nothing is working!

Comment: If you want pure xaml solution, you should pre-define those rows/columns and set their width/height to `0`, and then manually update them in a visual state.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried something like that:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells["Column6"].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```